# StarKill riddle in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Riddle:

Return a version of the given string, where for every star (*) in the string the star and the chars immediately to its left and right are gone. So "ab*cd" yields "ad" and "ab**cd" also yields "ad".

I'm wondering if there's a *pythonish* way to improve this algorithm:

```
def starKill(string): 

    result = ''

    for idx in range(len(string)):

        if(idx == 0 and string[idx] != '*'):
            result += string[idx]
        elif (idx > 0 and string[idx] != '*' and (string[idx-1]) != '*'):
            result += string[idx]
        elif (idx > 0 and string[idx] == '*' and (string[idx-1]) != '*'):
            result = result[0:len(result) - 1]

    return result
```

starKill("wacy*xko") **yields** wacko

Comment: Ind is a very confusing name for an index variable (at least to me) unfortunately I can't say much about your question on the phone.

Comment: Can you explain why `"ab**cd"` should become `"ad"`? You wrote that _for every star (*) in the string the star and the chars immediately to its left and right are gone_, which makes me think that the result should be `"acd"`.

Comment: `ind` is a confusing name for an index?

Comment: @AMC. Only if you think sequentially left to right rather than holistically

Comment: @MadPhysicist Enlighten me?

Comment: I think the riddle (that came from Java riddles) consider a "char" just alphabetical chars...

Comment: @AMC. Create a mask of stars, blur it one element left and one element right, remove masked items from string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by iterating over the string three times in parallel. Each iteration will be shifted relative to the next by one character. The middle one is the one that will provide the valid letters, the other two let us check if adjacent characters are stars. The two flanking iterators require dummy values to represent "before the start" and "after the end" of the string. There are a variety of ways to set that up, I'm using `itertools.chain` (and `.islice`) to fill in `None` for the dummy values. But you could use plain string and iterator manipulation if you prefer (i.e. `iter('x' + string)` and `iter(string[1:] + 'x')`):

```
import itertools

def star_kill(string):
    main_iterator = iter(string)
    look_behind = itertools.chain([None], string)
    look_ahead = itertools.chain(itertools.islice(string, 1, None), [None])

    return "".join(a for a, b, c in zip(main_iterator, look_behind, look_ahead)
                     if a != '*' and b != '*' and c != '*')
```

Comment: I've enjoyed all the help here. Thank you!  This itertools solution is what I've been looking for. Python to the core!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a numpy solution just for fun:

```
def star_kill(string, target='*'):
    arr = np.array(list(string))
    mask = arr != '*'
    mask[1:] &= mask[:-1]
    mask[:-1] &= mask[1:]
    arr = arr[mask]
    return arr[mask].view(dtype=f'U{arr.size}').item()
```

Comment: Nice to see some ML solution!

Comment: @andrade_philips What's ML?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression?

```
>>> import re
>>> for s in "ab*cd", "ab**cd", "wacy*xko", "*Mad*Physicist*":
        print(re.sub(r'\w?\*\w?', '', s))

ad
ad
wacko
ahysicis
```

Comment: Does it work if you have a star at the start or finish? It should, but I can't check right now. +1 regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether or not it's "Pythonic," but the problem can be solved with regular expressions.

```
import re

def starkill(s):
  s = re.sub(".{0,1}\\*{1,}.{0,1}", "", s)
  return s
```

For those not familiar with regex, I'll break that long string down:

**Prefix**

```
".{0,1}"
```

This specifies we want the replaced section to begin with either 0 or 1 of any character. If there is a character before the star, we want to replace it; otherwise, we still want the expression to hit if the star is at the very beginning of the input string.

**Star**

```
"\\*{1,}"
```

This specifies that the middle of the expression must contain an asterisk character, but it can also contain more than one. For instance, "a****b" will still hit, even though there are four stars. We need a backslash before the asterisk because regex has asterisk as a reserved character, and we need a second backslash before *that* because Python strings reserve the backslash character.

**Suffix**

```
.{0,1}
```

Same as the prefix. The expression can either end with one or zero of any character.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Looks like Heap Overflow beat me to the punch, and had a cleaner expression as well. Regardless, regex seems like a good solution!

Comment: You can use special characters to handle the repetitions you're checking for. The character `?` is equivalent to `{0,1}`, and `+` is equivalent to `{1,}`.